# How to automate showing thumbnail images in Home page of my custom Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, customization, blogs

Ok, After searching a lot, I am stuck with this problem. Currently I am doing this manually for every post. The Wordpress method either puts a custom snippet(defined for every post) or generates a small snippet on its own(using the method the_excerpt()).

The problem is that the snippet doesnt have the thumbnail image of the first image from the post.

Reference Link: http://www.azuyo.com/blogs

Here is the code from the index.php:

```
<?php
    the_excerpt();
?>
```

Here is the custom html I create manually for every post:

```
<a href="http://azuyo.com/blogs/2013/08/21/its-time-to-give-your-business-the-mobile-app-advantage/"><img src="http://azuyo.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/theworld-150x150.jpg" alt="theworld" width="150" height="150" hspace="10" vspace="10" class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-895" /></a>

Excerpt Text

</a> <a href="http://azuyo.com/blogs/2013/08/21/its-time-to-give-your-business-the-mobile-app-advantage">read more</a>
```

How do I automate this?

Comment: related to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45543/include-an-image-within-auto-the-excerpt, check the answer here

Comment: I checked that and I tried it out and it has no effect.

Comment: ok, can you tell me the files you modified and attach source code.

Answer (score 0):

put the following function into your theme functions.php

```
function trim_excerpt($text) {
        global $post;
        if ( '' == $text ) {
                $text = get_the_content('');
                $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
                $text = str_replace('\]\]\>', ']]&gt;', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', '', $text);
                $text = strip_tags($text, '<img>');
                $excerpt_length = 80;
                $words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);
                if (count($words)> $excerpt_length) {
                        array_pop($words);
                        array_push($words, '[...]');
                        $text = implode(' ', $words);
                }
        }
        return $text;
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'trim_excerpt');
```

Note the following line is where you're telling the function to strip all tags except  tags. You could add others if you'd like to include paragraph tags or whatever:

```
$text = strip_tags($text, '<img>');
```

there after you can call the the_excerpt(); asusual